# How to add progress bar or progress ring for webview project for windows mobile app

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have created a Webview Project for windows phone app to load google.com. It's working fine but I'm unable to add a Progress bar or Progress Ring. Can any one please help me?

```
namespace App2
{
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {

      private static readonly Uri HomeUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);

      public MainPage()
      {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
      }

      protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
      {
         WebViewControl.Navigate(HomeUri);
         HardwareButtons.BackPressed += this.MainPage_BackPressed;
      }

      protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
      {
         HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= this.MainPage_BackPressed;
      }

      private void MainPage_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (WebViewControl.CanGoBack)
         {
            WebViewControl.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
         }
      }

      private void Browser_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
      {
         if (!args.IsSuccess)
         {
            Debug.WriteLine("Navigation to this page failed, check your internet connection.");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you should add progress ring/bar in your .xaml(view).

Comment: Hi Chirag Shah, i added the ring in .xaml, but  It shows the error as " The Property 'Content' is set more than once".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML add a progress ring over the webview so that it overlaps webview for example

```
<Grid>
     <Grid x:Name="webViewHolder" >
                    <WebView x:Name="wvPage" Loaded="WebView_Loaded" NavigationCompleted="WebView_NavigationCompleted" NavigationStarting="wvPage_NavigationStarting"></WebView>
                </Grid>

                <ProgressRing  x:Name="myProgressRing" IsActive="True" Height="90" Width="90" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#EF4D17"/>
</Grid>
```

Now in code Behind

```
private void wvPage_NavigationStarting(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {            
            myProgressRing.IsActive = true;
        }
.
.
.
 private void WebView_NavigationCompleted(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            myProgressRing.IsActive = false;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks jerin and every one . i have done what you given here. It shows the error in the XAML file. I got the error as " The Property 'Content'  is set more than once".

Comment: Make sure you enclose both webview and progressring inside a grid.See my edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much Jerin. Its Working!!. I'm really happy with your answer and support.

Comment: Np bro thats what stackoverflow is for. Also in future pls refrain from saying `thanks` as it might lead to down votes.